# Add logs in different directory using daemon in ruby

Tags: ruby, daemon, logrotate, daemons

I am using daemon to wrap my script and has specified logs location into that :
Script looks like this :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run_proc(
   'script_test', # name of daemon
   :log_output => true,
   :output_logfilename => "script-test.log",
   :logfilename => "script-test.log"
 ) do
   exec 'ruby /opt/script-test/script-test.rb'
end
```

Problem is my logs are storing in same directory where my script is present. I have to add my logs to different directory such as /var/log/script-test and later have to rotate those logs weekly.
Provide me with a solution so that i can store the logs of script in /var/log directory.

Comment: May be you can try some Gems like [this - log4net](https://rubygems.org/gems/log4net/versions/1.2.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with this configuration as :

```
Daemons.run_proc(
   'script-test', # name of daemon
   :log_output => true,
   :dir_mode => :normal,
   :dir => "/var/log",
   :output_logfilename => "script-test.log",
   :logfilename => "script-test.log"
 ) do
   exec 'ruby /opt/script-test/script-test.rb'
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using an absolute path instead of a relative path

For example:

```
:output_logfilename => "/var/log/script-test.log",
:logfilename => "/var/log/script-test.log"
```

In order to logrotate your logs, (assuming Linux) add the following to your `logrotate` config to rotate on a weekly basis:

```
/var/log/script-test.log {
  weekly
  missingok
  compress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

Comment: I changed that but no luck. this doesnot create any log file in /var/log directory. Thanks for sharing logrotate script though.

Comment: As a temp test, try to create file first with `sudo touch /var/log/script-test.log` and then `sudo chmod 777 /var/log/script-test.log`.